# C# constructor calling

Tags: c#

Simple question, how can I solve this?

```
public MyClass(string s)
{
    int k = s.Length;
    int l = SomeFunction(s);
    int m = GetNumber();
    if (Valid(l, m))
    {
       int p = SomeOtherFunction(k, m);
       MyBigObject o = new MyBigObject(p);
       // here I want to call the other constructor MyClass(o)
    }
}
public MyClass(MyBigObject x)
{
   this.o = x;
}
```

Comment: sounds like homework to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the common functionality and wrap it into a separate method.

```
public MyClass(string s)
{
    int k = s.Length;
    int l = SomeFunction(s);
    int m = GetNumber();
    if (Valid(l, m))
    {
       int p = SomeOtherFunction(k, m);
       MyBigObject o = new MyBigObject(p);
       this.init(o);
    }
}

public MyClass(MyBigObject x)
{
   this.init(x);
}

public void init(MyBigObject x)
{
   this.o = x;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with the following code:

```
public MyClass(string s) : this(s.Length)
{ 
}
public MyClass(int x)
{
   this.n = x;
}
```

For your edited question:

```
public MyClass(string s) : this(ConstructorHelper(s))
{
}
public MyClass(MyBigObject x)
{
   this.o = x;
}

private static MyBigObject ConstructorHelper(string s)
{
    int k = s.Length;
    int l = SomeFunction(s);
    int m = GetNumber();
    if (Valid(l, m))
    {
       int p = SomeOtherFunction(k, m);
       MyBigObject o = new MyBigObject(p);
       return o;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MyClass(string s) : this(s.Length)
{
    // 
}

public MyClass(int x)
{
   this.n = x;
}
```